# To which the bolded phrase refers to? "aristocratic control" or "reducing aristocratic control"?

Tags: relative-pronouns

I've assumed that *Which was* is eliminated between the word *Control* and *Already*.

> By the end of the century, the time was ripe for more change: the tyrants were driven out, and in 508 B.C. a new reformer, Cleisthenes, gave final form to the developers reducing aristocratic control **already under way**.

P.S. My answer would be *aristocratic control* but I am not sure. 
If it is referred to "reducing aristocratic control", why *which was* is eliminated?

Comment: Semantic considerations suggest that it is was the reduction which was already under way, but the sentence is so convoluted as to be almost impenetrable.

Comment: I think ***developers'*** should have that possessive apostrophe, since the reference is to ***their** reduction of aristocratic control [**which was** already under way].*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first place, this passage almost certainly contains a typo: *gave final form to the **developers*** is very odd, and a little Googling around shows that other sites have *developments* instead of *developers*.

In that context, I think we are to understand *already under way* as an adjunct to *developments reducing aristocratic control* — that is, these developments were already under way, and Cleisthenes gave them their final form.

As to why *which were* is "eliminated": there's no reason to think it was ever there. Preposition phrases ordinarily follow the nominals they modify (think of *the man in the street* or *the city on the hill*), and *already under way* is a preposition phrase which includes a leading adverb modifier.

(There are, I concede, linguists who claim that all postpositive adjectivals are "reduced relative clauses"—that is, relative clauses from which the initial *wh- BE* piece has been deleted. But my opinion is that this is baloney.)

Comment: Re "the initial wh- BE piece has been deleted"... As you know, I don't claim to know much about correct terminology in such matters. But having been familiarized with the usage by John Lawler, I often refer to "optional" elements like ***which was*** in my comment above as "deleted" even in contexts where it might be screamingly obvious to me that actually *including* the extra text would be extremely unidiomatic. Are you saying that from *your* perspective, if it wouldn't normally be present anyway, it's not a "reduced relative clause" and "deleted" is a misleading way to refer to it?

Comment: @FumbleFingers You understand me precisely. I think there is another rule which accounts for these postpositions more economically.

Comment: Well, I'm certainly not going to take sides between you and John! (I might have misunderstood how he uses "deleted" anyway.) But even if we accept that ***which was/were*** was never present in order to be deleted, I'd have thought *imagining* it being there might help OP understand what the text means.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I tend to be a little picky on points like this precisely because useful paraphrases are often taught in terms which suggest to the learner that the paraphrase is the more "proper" or more "real" manner of expressing a thought -- as here, where OP asks "Why was X  eliminated?"

Comment: oic. Yes, I do sometimes roll my eyes when it seems to me a learner has walked away with the impression that some unnaturally verbose paraphrasing presented here purely to help *understanding* is in fact "more correct". But the problem for me is I don't always *know* what uber-pedants would consider "correct" in the first place (plus I'm the kind of guy who's liable to take umbrage if someone criticizes my phrasing! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Do what I do: figure out what **you** would write and then come up with a plausible (but not necessarily valid) reason why it's better than the alternative.

Comment: Hmm. I really hate the "full" version [*If I **would have** lost you*](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/62490/2637). It's nearly always contracted anyway, but if I'm *forced* to "expand", I will always prefer *If I [**had have**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22if+I+had+have%22) lost you*. I'm completely unable to come up with a plausible reason for my position - which superficially seems like syntactic nonsense, I admit. Given it sets John Lawler's teeth on edge, I'd be putting my head in the lion's mouth if I tried to justify it. But at least he accepts change is inevitable.

Comment: (So if I'm lucky, I might be ahead of the curve on that one.)

Comment: *If I would have lost you* isn't a "full" version; the "correct" version is *If I had lost you*. You could call it an "expanded" version: if you hear somebody actually say it it can safely be regarded as a hypercorrection. BUT My guess is that most of the time it's an orthographic expansion not of the construction but of a spoken "If I'da ...", as I suspect your *had have* is. And *that* is one of the most interesting things that's happened to English in the last century or so: the evolution of positive and negative bound morphemes *-da* and *-dna* which get tacked on to various forms  ...

Comment: ... (or absences) of *HAVE* as markers of nonfactuality. In effect, they're novel affixes or clitics. Dare I suggest that we've passed the turning point of the grammaticalization cycle and we're now beginning to move back toward being a synthetic language? starting with reinvention of the subjunctive?!

Comment: @FumbleFingers There's an _uber?_

Comment: I think the Internet is causing a real explosion in the rate of non-Anglophones' exposure to English - both non-interactive *verbal, spoken* (movies, Youtube, etc.) and interactive (primarily *written*, as in chatrooms, help forums, etc.). But for many nns there's probably no corresponding increase in exposure to *verbal interaction* (where they have to *generate* speech in contexts with inherent feedback so they know they're at least getting it right enough to be understood). Will the dead hand of orthography maintain its grip as the language evolves? Truly, we live in "interesting times".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Puh-leeze! ... us pro orthographs ain't all dead yet; and we prefer to think of it as "maintaining continuity with the Tradition".

Comment: The likes of you and me are reasonably comfortable reading Shakespeare (even without modernized spelling), but I imagine I'd have considerable difficulty if I could be somehow exposed to the spoken version of the time. (Yeah, yeah! I'm quite prepared to believe *you* could even handle an authentic spoken version of Chaucer, which would probably be totally opaque to me! :) Orthography has changed little since Webster, but semantics, syntactic structures, and articulation keep drifting away from any supposed "fixed standard" implied by the way we write things down.